# Google Script to hide rows in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I have Google sheet with Product Type column (with following dropdown values Type 1, Type and Type) and rows as shown in picture. I am trying to achieve using google script to show only the rows based on Product Type value (if I select Type 1, I want to hide the rows which have Type 2 and Type 3 values in the same column). Here I cannot use a filter because there are some titles in some rows. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Would you please share a copy of your spreadsheet, Would also explain your comment about filter "Here I cannot use filter because there are some titles in some rows."

Comment: I agreed with Tedinoz. Could you share some code and give us more details about your question? Here a link to learn how to do a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please see if this answers your query - https://yagisanatode.com/2018/05/26/how-to-hide-a-row-based-on-a-cell-value-in-google-sheets-with-filter-or-google-apps-script/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You want to hide or show rows, depending on the selected type in cell A1

Here is a simple script that runs automatically [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), i.e. every time a cell in the spreadsheet is edited. It uses the methods [showRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showrowsrowindex) and [hideRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideRows(Integer)) and compares the entries in column A against the value in cell A1. It hides all the rows where the entry contains the word "Type", but is not the selected type.

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // adapt to your needs
  var toShow=sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var startRow=10 //adapt to your needs
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log(lastRow);
  for (i = startRow; i <= 320; i++) {
    var type = sheet.getRange("A" + i).getValue();
    if (type == toShow||toShow=="Product Type") {
      sheet.showRows(i);
      Logger.log('row '+i+' shown');
    }
  }
  for (i = startRow; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var type = sheet.getRange("A" + i).getValue();
    if (type != toShow && type.indexOf('Type')!=-1) {      
      Logger.log(i+'i hidden');
      sheet.hideRows(i);
    }
  }
}
```

> You need to bind the script to your spreadsheet and run it manually
>   once - to trigger authorization flow.

Comment: Thank you for your script. But I want to hide the rows based on the type I selected from the Project Type value. If I select Type 2 then I want to hide rows which has Type1 and Type 3 vice versa, Any suggestion? I am knew to this scripting.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the issue. I just updated my code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. Script is working fine but it’s hiding all the rows which is not needed. There are titles and I don’t want to avoid irrespective of the product type value and this script is hiding all rows when I load because it is applying script for “Product Type” as well(it is a title of drop down), which is not needed. I tried to update script but it is not working as expected. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want the script to start hiding/showing rows starting from row 11 - please modify `var startRow=2` to `var startRow=11`. Does it solve the issue?

Comment: Maybe you can provide a copy of your sheet (without confidential data), so I can understand your request better?

Comment: No. It doesn't solve the issue. On the Top I have Product Type title with three options(Type 1, Type 2, Type).  Data is as follows. I want to show Type 1 rows and hide Type 2 and Type 3 in all sections (I do not want to hide Section A, Section B, Section C) if I select Type 1 from Product Type and I want to show only Type 2 and hide Type 1 and 3 rows if I select Type 2 from Product Type and vice versa. I hope you got clear idea now.

Product Type
Section A
Type 1
Type 2
Type 3
Section B
Type 1
Type 2
Type 2
Type 3
Section C
Type 1
Type 2
Type 3
Type 1

Comment: Where are Section A, Section B and Section C located? It is hard for me to understand the problem without seeing your sheet / a screenshot of it which contains all the relevant information. Are we talking about hiding rows based on values in column A, or also other columns?

Comment: Only based on Column A. Attached screen capture.

Comment: Now I understand the issue, please see my updated answer.

Comment: It is working as expected. Thank you very much Sir.

Comment: I am trying to unhide all rows if Product Type is selected but it is not working. Updated script is added below.Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); var toShow=sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
   var startRow=2 //adapt to your needs
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log(lastRow);
  for (i = startRow; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var type = sheet.getRange("A" + i).getValue();
    if (type == toShow && toShow != "Product Type") {
      sheet.showRows(i); }
    else if(toShow == "Product Type") {
   var rowRange = sheet.getRange(10,A, 300, 1); 
  var datarange = sheet.unhideRow(rowRange);
    }
  } }

Comment: Several things: 1. When you use the method `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)` you need to specify the columm as a number ( 1 instead of Ä. 2. `unhideRow(range)` unhides only the first row of a range - you want to unhide all rows, right? Then you should better use `sheet.showRows(rowIndex, numRows)`. You do not need it though, since the`for loop` already implements `showRows(i)` I updated the code in my answer implementing "Product Type" and making the script loop through the rows 10 to 320 (Is that what you want?). Keep in mind that for over 300 rows the script might be slow.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Your script is working fine but here Product Type is just title and Type 1, Type 2 and Type 3 are sub values(drop down) of Product Type. Now if I select Type 1 from Product Type, script is hiding Type 2 and 3 and showing only Type 1 rows and it is hiding Type 1 and 3 for Type 2 and so on.  If I select "Product Type" back then all the hidden rows should display because it is just title and there are no rows with that value.

Comment: I thought this is what you wanted. If not, please try to explain in other words.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working but sometimes for some rows it's not working, means it's not hiding or unhiding. Sheet has more than 100 rows. There is no consistency. What could be the reasons and how to debug?

Comment: I did check logs and it's showing Time Out error. Why I am getting time out error?Any idea?

Comment: I see. Do you get the timeout error also if you change `for (i = startRow; i <= 320; i++) ` to `for (i = startRow; i <= 120; i++) `? As I mentioned before, hiding and showing rows is a slow process, depending on your numbe rof row you might exceed the quota of maximum Script runtime (6 min for free users) https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas. If 6 min is not enough to loop through all your rows, you might have to split the script in two subscripts (e.g. one for rows 1-100), the second for rows (100-200).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one question. I want to create one more custom filter in same sheet based on another cell value(ex: C7). So do I need to create separate project or can I add one more if condition in the same script with necessary changes?

Comment: You can implement it into the same script and function, indeed you cannot have more than one onEdit() function per project because it can lead to conflicts.

Comment: Hi Sir, I am trying to filter if row contains a value = value of c8 but not working. 
var ptoShow=sheet.getRange("C8").getValue();
  var pStartRow =9
  var toShow=sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var startRow=2 
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log(lastRow);
  for (i = startRow; i <= 200; i++) {
    var type = sheet.getRange("A" + i).getValue();
    var pType = sheet.getRange("C" + i).getValue();
    if (type == toShow||toShow=="Project Type") {
      sheet.showRows(i);
    }
    if(pType.indexOf(ptoShow)>-1) {
       sheet.showRows(i);
     
    }
  }

Comment: Your script as it is will show rows that contain the value of `A1` in column A,  rows with the content "Project type" and rows that contain the value of  `C8` in column C. Is this intended behavior?

Comment: no. C8 is the another filter(drop down). If I select value in C8, then all the rows which does not contain selected value in column C should be hidden.

Comment: Your code does not have any method to hide rows, only to show them. To hide rows you need to implement `if(pType.indexOf(ptoShow)=-1) { sheet.hideRows(i); }`